# Temp1 overheat SpeedFan - 97°C

Tags: laptop, cooling, temperature

I have HP Omen 17 inch, which I believe I bought 2 years ago. I cleaned it several times the last one was 2 weeks ago. The thermal paste haven't been changed since I bought it. I also have IETS GT300 cooling pad, which keeps the temperatures way lower, but right now I'm not home and no cooling pad and the temperatures are way higher.

The question is what exactly is Temp1 and 97 degrees Celsius probably means that it is time to change the thermal paste, is that correct?

[image]

This is from HWmonitor

[image]

#### Edit

I had the laptop turned off for a while and this is right after I started it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's not normal. Do I have to replce the thermal paste?

#### Edit2:

After I plugged off the power cable, the laptop is now cold, the temperatures are normal and I can't even hear the fans which is good. I read  [this post](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Gaming-Notebooks/HP-Omen-overheating-97-100C/td-p/6709201/page/2), which says that if I disable the turbo CPU boost or whatever, it will make it just like it is right now without the charger. Is it true and how do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Your laptop doesn’t have thermal paste it has a thermal pad, those temperatures look normal, is your cpu temperatures causing hard shutdown? If the answer to that question is no then your laptop is unlikely to be overheating.  If your thermal paste was “misplaced” then your cpu would instantly within 5 seconds reach its thermal limits.

Comment: @nop - You want to decrease the performance of your laptop even though it’s NOT overheating or thermally throttling? I can’t help you do something that won’t resolve your non-existing problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, I bought a `compressed air flow` spray and cleaned the fans, now the temperatures are a bit less. https://i.imgur.com/BYMD7Di.png and this is while playing League of Legends.

Comment: Your linked image in your comment is inaccessible to me.